# Yii: Restfullyii extension accessRules on restEvents

Tags: php, rest, yii

He there,

I've been using the restfullyii extension for a while now, and everything is working great.
(http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/restfullyii/)

I was just wondering if the following is possible:

- Admin is allowed to do all REST.GET, REST.PUT, REST.POST and REST.DELETE
- Normal users can only use the own defined ones in restEvents.

accessRules is looking like this:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', 
            'actions'=>array('REST.GET.SPECIAL'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' actions
            'actions'=>array('REST.GET', 'REST.PUT', 'REST.POST', 'REST.DELETE'),
            'users'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->getAdmins(),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

restEvents is looking like this:

```
public function restEvents()
{ 
    $this->onRest('req.get.special.render', function() {
        /// blabla code
    });
}
```

I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the following:

```
 /**
 * req.auth.uri
 *
 * return true to allow access to a given uri / http verb;
 * false to deny access to a given uri / http verb;
 *
 * @return (bool) default is true
 */ 
$this->onRest(req.auth.uri, function($uri, $verb) {
    return true;
});
```

This will allow you to block/allow particular users in the controller. Just put it in the restEvents() method.